# Dictionary comprehension python

Tags: dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following dictionary:

```py
cars_info_with_colors = {
    "red": {"audi": [105, 55], "toyota": [105, 66]}, 
    "blue": {"renault": [102, 33], "mercedes": [100, 80]}
}
```

I want to have the nested dictionary's only and I can do it like that:

```py
removed_colors_dict = {}

for car in cars_info_with_colors:
    cars_info_without_colors.update(cars_info_with_colors[car])

# output:

removed_colors_dict = {
    'audi': [105, 55],
    'toyota': [105, 66],
    'renault': [102, 33],
    'mercedes': [100, 80]
}
```

I want to do it with dictionary comprehension but i have failed multiply times.
I will be really thankful if someone can show me how can I do it, thank you a lot! Have a wonderful day!
(sorry for gramma and bad explanations!)

Thats some of the ways I tried to do it:

```py
{k: v for k, v in cars_with_colors.values}
{k: v for k, v in cars_with_colors for v in cars_with_colors.values]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```py
cars_info_with_colors = {
    "red": {"audi": [105, 55], "toyota": [105, 66]}, 
    "blue": {"renault": [102, 33], "mercedes": [100, 80]}
}

result = {k2:v2 for k1,v1 in cars_info_with_colors.items() for k2,v2 in v1.items()}
#         k1='red' v1={'audi':[...], ...}        k2 ='audi',v2=[105,55]

print(result)
```

Since we want the key and value of the dictionary that are the values of the top level `(key,value)` combo... you need to run another for loop within the comprehension to extract and flatten those values.

output:

```py
{'audi': [105, 55],
 'toyota': [105, 66],
 'renault': [102, 33],
 'mercedes': [100, 80]}
```